# Array for storing names and grades of students in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to make a small program in C which will store the first name, last name, and grade of an user inputted number of students. My biggest issue so far is on how to get for the names and grades of each student to print in a new line. With the string operator, I get an error, and with the char operator I only get the first letter and the grade. How would I go about getting the names to fully print? Thanks for all the help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){
  int classsize,i;

  printf("Please indicate number of records you want to enter (min 5, max 15):\n");
  scanf("%d", &classsize);

  char *first, *last;
  double *mark;

  first=(char*)malloc(classsize*sizeof(char));
  last=(char*)malloc(classsize*sizeof(char));
  mark=(double*)malloc(classsize*sizeof(double));



  printf("Please input records of students (enter a new line after each record), with following format 1. first name 2. last name 3. score.\n");
  for (i=0; i<classsize; i++) {
    scanf("%s", &first[i]);
    scanf("%s", &last[i]);
    scanf("%lf", &mark[i]);
  }

  for (i=0; i<classsize; i++) {
    printf("%s, %s has a %lf\n", *(first+i), *(last+i), *(mark+i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
char *first, *last;
```

You can store only 1 string in the variables as string in `C` is `char *`. `first` is `char *` and `first[i]` is `char` so you have errors related to that. You want `first` to be `char **` and `first[i]` as `char *`.

You want

```
char **first, **last;
```

And change allocation to (*note you don't need to typecast `malloc`*)

```
//---------------------------------v
first=malloc(classsize*sizeof(char *));
```

And then in for loop allocate memory for each `char *` in `first` and `last` before reading names in that.

```
first[i] = malloc(some_size * sizeof(char));
...
```